# How to start Tomcat with output on console in Linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I know it's possible to start tomcat and then run `tail -f catalina.out` to view Tomcat output. But how to run tomcat and view output at once? Are there some options to run `startup.sh` with?

Comment: You need to do `./catalina.sh run`. If you view usage of catalina.sh you will see `run  ->  Start Catalina in the current window`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to move this question to https://serverfault.com/?.

Comment: For Linux distributions where `catalina.sh` is not available after installing Tomcat from a package, something like the following could work: `sudo -u tomcat /usr/libexec/tomcat/server start` (tested in Amazon Linux 2 with `tomcat8` package installed).

Comment: what about 'sudo -u tomcat /usr/libexec/tomcat/server start' for tomcat9 ?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You're looking for

```
tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

instead of

```
tomcat/bin/startup.sh; tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Tomcat stays in foreground this way (first option). If you want to shut it down, Ctrl-C in your console window will do the trick.

If you choose the second option, tomcat will run in background, while tail will run in foreground, but you'll have to give the same directory path twice.

Comment: interesting, it mirrors Java's `Thread.start()` vs `Thread.run()` which I also used to confuse.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using service, `cd` to Tomcat's bin directory, type `./startup.sh`. This will start Tomcat in console.

All the logs that goes to catalina.out you can modify it by this link : [Tomcat logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q6)