# How can I run Tomcat Startup Script in Existing terminal window?

Tags: tomcat

To start Tomcat 10 I am using `startup.bat`, which then opens another terminal window and I will be able to see logs in that terminal screen. But I don't want another terminal window, I want the server to run in the existing terminal window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Tomcat with output on console in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010448/how-to-start-tomcat-with-output-on-console-in-linux) (replace `.sh` with `.bat`, of course)

Comment: yeah something like that but I need Windows Specific Solution ! 'coz Windows does not have `tail command.

Comment: There is no need for tail. In fact, the answer mentions specifically that you don't need it

Comment: The Answer says that if I were to run tomcat Server in backgroud then the Output will be stored in catalina.out file and inorder to see the output I will have to use tail -f to read as well as follow the changes in that file. So, I'll need something like tail to continuously read that log file.

Comment: The answer contains more than you need. `catalina.bat run` is all you need, and it will show the output in the current terminal. Simply ignore the part after _"instead of"_

Comment: just `cataline.bat run` will open a new terminal window. I have tried. I dont want that Extra Terminal Window.